# How to create universal callto (tel://) phone header location?

Tags: php, header

I need to create page that will be launch call to phone number function. I use this code:

```
header("Location: tel:+79999999999");
exit();
```

It's work good on smartphones, but not work on desktops. How to create universal call phone function?

Answer (score 1):

The `tel://` scheme's availability on your clients' browsers is dependent on:

- if the browser supports said scheme, and
- if the user has an application on their device to handle the request.

The reason `header("Location: tel:+79999999999");` may only be working on your phone is because your phone has an app to handle such request; whereas your PC may not.

---

> How to create universal call phone function?

Using `header("Location: tel:+79999999999");` is the closest thing you'll get to what you're looking for (after all, you can't force a user to phone a number if they don't have the means to do so!)

Comment: But I have example, that works on Desktops: http://api.sms.intel-tele.com/callto/+78126034322/

How they did that?

Comment: That page comes up completely blank for me. When the client makes a phone call on their phone, that gets taken off of their phone credit and the call is made. I'm not aware of any VOIP solutions which offer free Internet calling to a telephone number.

Comment: It's blank because close after visit it. I check this page for headers and it's returning also tel://, but my page not calling VOIP http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php